# Как Series[0] записать в массив ? delphi

Tags: delphi

Как `Series[0]` записать в массив ?
Я делаю так, но там ошибку выдаёт в строке 7 ('('expected but'['found)

```
 public
    type XSeriesZero = array [0..1000] of real;
  end;
...
    for i:=0 to FDub5.Chart1.Series[0].Count do
      begin
       XSeriesZero[i]:= FDub5.Chart1.Series[0].XValues.Value[i]; // ошибка!
       ShowMessage(FloatToStr(XSeriesZero[i]));
      end;
```

Comment: `XSeriesZero` - это тип, а не переменная.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XSeriesZero` - это тип, а не переменная.

```
type 
  XSeriesZero = array [0..1000] of real;

var
  xValues: XSeriesZero;

...
for i := 0 to FDub5.Chart1.Series[0].Count do
begin
  xValues[i] := FDub5.Chart1.Series[0].XValues.Value[i]; // нет ошибки!
  ShowMessage(FloatToStr(xValues[i]));
end;
```

Comment: Ошибка в строке :xValues: XSeriesZero; Undeclared identifier 'XSeriesZero'